How do vehicle transmissions modify torque?
I'm really having problems understanding the inner workings of transmissions on a physics level. For an example, a motorcycle dogbox. I want to find the force on the 5th gear in the transmission at peak torque. From taking the motorcyle to a dyno, I know the exact torque at the rear wheel at a given RPM, 316 Nm at 10000 RPMs in 5th gear. Note that this value is supposed to be similar to the rated crank torque of the engine.
Now, with a rear wheel of diameter 21", for there to be a 1:1 ratio of angular velocity between the wheel and the engine, take wheel circum. = 65.97"
multiplied by 10000 RPMs = 659700 inch/min = 624.72 MPH.
From technical manuals and sprocket calculators, I know for a fact that at 10,000 RPMs, the actual velocity in 5th is ~240 MPH.
Therefore, the ratio of the entire drivetrain and rear wheel in 5th gear is 2.6.
Now, from the formula for output torque of gearing, To = Ti r μ, 316 Nm = Mi (2.6)* 1 (for this purpose assume 100% efficiency). This would put the engine torque at the crankshaft at 121 Nm.
Obviously this isn't even remotely true, crank torque is usually 10% or more HIGHER than wheel torque.
Inertia dynamometers use the principle that the energy consumed by the engine and turned into power will be the same amount that is calculated from the mass and angular velocity of the metal drum being spun by the tire P = τ × ω. And this makes sense to me. But how is this the case if the torque must be different for there to be a difference in the angular velocity of the wheel and engine? if the energy consumed by the engine is independent of gearing then why does the dyno read a higher number if tested in 1st gear instead of 5th?
That's my thought process for this. What I'm trying to do is find the force on the pressure line of the 5th driven gear in the transmission by the engine. Would this value just be the rated wheel torque? Or is the actual rear wheel torque 316Nm * 2.6 = 821.6 Nm and I'm doing this in reverse? I was hoping that by knowing the ratio between the crankshaft gear and clutch gear, then the 5th driving and driven gears, and then the final drive I would be able to trace the force from the wheel back through the system and find the load on the gears.
I may be in over my head trying to find this, but if anything I'm even more curious on how exactly transmissions effect torque to the rear wheels.
Thank you.

"Obviously this isn't even remotely true, crank torque is usually 10% or more HIGHER than wheel torque." you discarded friction losses and usually doesn't mean always.

What happens when you take the final drive ratio into account?  Unless you're building that motorcycle for the lakes, you'll have a bigger sprocket on the rear wheel than on the transmission output shaft.

you're forgetting about the differential

one question per post, please!
